# How do I transfer my Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation, pokemon-fifth-generation

So I have my Pokémon from Diamond (yes I have Diamond; no I don't think it's emasculating) and I want to transfer them over to my new Pokémon Black.   Seems easy enough.

But here is the catch: **I only have 1 DS**.

How do I accomplish this feat?

Comment: With just 1 DS, I believe the sad answer is "you don't". :( Leaving as a comment in the hopes that someone can correct me.

Comment: Yup, you need two DSes (unfortunately there's no way around this). Perhaps a friend of yours has a DS that you could borrow?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree: diamonds aren't emasculating.

Comment: Diamond has Honchkrow. That's about as anti-emasculating as you can get.

Comment: When your choice is between "Diamond" and "Pearl", you're really SOL

Comment: @Sapph so what you're saying is that friendless losers (or people who hide their Pokémon obsession from IRL friends for fear of being ostracized; what? I grew up with Pokémon, it first came out when I was 10!) have no hope of transfering forwards their hard won Pokémon?

Comment: Make friends :P It shouldn't be hard to find someone with a DS.

Comment: @tzenes: You need better friends! My group of friends ostracized the kid who *didn't* want Pokemon B/W until he caved and bought it! :D

Comment: Solution: Stand in your local video game store and stare at people until they surrender their DS to you.

Comment: @tzenes You could do like a friend of mine might do. Knowing someone who locally has 2 DSes and would collaborate with you to do a 4-gen global trade → transfer from 4-gen to 5-gen → 5-gen global trade back, that can help.

Comment: @Grace Clearly the what I need to do is be more like you, so I can have cool friend like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot transfer your Pokemon over using only one DS.  You must use 2 separate units in order to transfer Pokemon from the 4th Generation games to the 5th Generation games.

Doing so if you have 2 DS units is fairly quick and simple, however.  Go west out of the Black City (or White Forest if you're playing White Version) a bit to get to the Pokemon Transfer Lab.  It will give you on-screen instructions on what to do with your other DS.  You can choose to transfer Pokemon out of any of the boxes in the 4th Generation game, but not the party.

Then you have to play a little silly diverting mini-game.  I've only transfered once, so I'm not sure what happens if you lose, but it is not a difficult game and it won't be difficult to win in short order.

Afterwards, all 6 Pokemon you chose are transfered to your box on the 5th Generation game.  You can do this as many times as you like in quick succession (unlike transferring from 3rd Generation games to 4th Generation games).

Comment: I had heard there was a way to trade Pokémon over the internet, possibly asynchronously?  I'm not familiar with the details...

Comment: @tzenes You can trade pokemon over the internet asynchronously by offering a pokemon for one matching certain criteria or seeking offered pokemon.  However, this doesn't work across generations either, so unfortunately you're still left unable to use this feature to move your pokemon from Gen4 to Gen5.

Comment: For reference, if you "lose" (=run out of time), only the Pokémon you got in time are transferred and the others are simply sent back to their boxes.

Answer (score 2):

If you were planning on getting a 3DS you could buy that (comes out this weekend, price has come down a huge amount already). It plays regular DS games so you will be able to trade between games.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would mean I could insert both Diamond and Black into the 3DS and transfer it that way?

Comment: @tzenes I believe he's talking about transferring between the DS and 3DS.  "On the off chance you're getting a 3DS, you can use it to do the transfer with your DS."

Comment: @tzenes Matthew is right, I meant trading between DS and 3DS. The 3DS has only one game slot AFAIK, but it will play both DS games and 3DS games and has the same connectivity.

Comment: +1, this is my plan. Picking up my 3DS (and Nintendogs! Who cares about emasculation!) Sunday morning and then transferring from my DS Lite.