# How do I transfer old Pokemon to Black/White with ONE Nintendo DS?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

I only have one Nintendo DS Lite. Most of my friends don't play games thus don't have a NDS. I want to transfer over some Pokemon such as Skitty, Delcatty, and a few others that I am not able to get. How can I get my old Pokemon over? I don't have my old GBA games sadly either. My Skitty (my favorite Pokemon...) is a shiny Skitty so it is important to me.

Comment: Transfer it from where?  If you don't have any of your old GBA games, where are they coming from?

Comment: Well I transferred my shiny Skitty over from Emerald to HeartGold. I want to get my HeartGold Pokemon (like Skitty) to Pokemon Black/White.

So basically: Emerald > HeartGold > Black or White

Comment: Don't think you can, I believe you'll need to borrow a friend's, but I'm not 100% certain of that (haven't done such on B/W)

Comment: According to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18808/how-do-i-transfer-my-pokemon/18818#18818), it's not possible with only a single DS.

Comment: Save up and buy a 3DS! You'll need it anyway for Pokemon X&Y in October :)

Comment: What about using the Dream service? I had someone tell me that they would check Pokemon into that from Black and then retrieve them Black 2. Maybe I misunderstood though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry to tell you, but you can't. You need to use another Nintendo DS (or DSi, 3DS, anything). The guy at the Transfer Lab even tells you that you need another one.

Answer (score -3):

From: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Transfer:

> Poké Transfer (Japanese: ポケシフター PokéShifter) is a feature in the Generation V games Pokémon Black and White and Pokémon Black and White 2. It is located in the Poké Transfer Lab on Route 15.
>
> The Poké Transfer is a feature that allows Pokémon from any Generation IV game to be transferred to Pokémon Black and White, similar to Generation IV's Pal Park. It can be visited after the main storyline of the games has been completed and the player has obtained the National Pokédex.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you please elaborate on how you could use the Poké Transfer to accomplish what the person who asked the question is looking for? Additionally, in the future please include the source when copying content off other sites.